# .htaccess old site redirect to new with each url separate redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have a website that is migrated to another URL. So I wanted to migrate my all previous URL to a new URL with a different segment. For example

1. Main redirect

   Old site is: https:// myoldsite.abc
   New Site is: https:// mynewsite.xyz
2. I also want to redirect all other pages to new URL

   Old site is: https:// myoldsite.abc/myfolder
   New Site is: https:// mynewsite.xyz/new_url_1

   Old site is: https:// myoldsite.abc/myfolder/old_url
   New Site is: https:// mynewsite.xyz/new_url_2

   Old site is: https:// myoldsite.abc/myfolder/abc_url
   New Site is: https:// mynewsite.xyz/new_url_3
3. Simple URLs

   Old site is: https:// myoldsite.abc/testing_url
   New Site is: https:// mynewsite.xyz/New_testing_url_1

My code looks something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myoldsite.abc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myoldsite.abc [NC]

RewriteRule ^/myfolder/url_1/?$  https://mynewsite.xyz/new_url_1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/url_2/?$  https://mynewsite.xyz/new_url_2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/url_3/?$  https://mynewsite.xyz/new_url_3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/url_4/?$ https://mynewsite.xyz/new_url_4 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/myfolder?$ https://mynewsite.xyz/new_url_4 [R=301,L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mynewsite.xyz [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting to use `.htaccess`? However, the directives you have posted are as if you are in the main server config? How many redirects are required? Presumably the old URLs do not exist at the new site? Do both the old and new domains point to the new site? And both domains function OK on the new site - if it wasn't for the redirect? What is the difference between #2 and #3? How are your URLs being routed / what other directives do you have?

Answer (score -1):

Your htaccess file should work, it should be placed in the root directory.

Have you tried Redirect instead?

> Redirect 301 /folder/ http://www.example.com/new_path/

Comment: Yes also not working.

Comment: Apparently you have to have a RewriteCond before each RewriteRule, Try this or Copy/Paste the Cond several times ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218164/multiple-rewriterules-for-single-rewritecond-in-htaccess

Comment: Is it possible that you can write some solution and I would test it? Thank you.

Comment: "Your htaccess file should work" - If these directives are in `.htaccess` (as suggested) then none of the specific redirects will work due to the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. You don't "have to have a RewriteCond before each RewriteRule" if the old URLs don't exist at the new site. The `Redirect` directive will likely cause issues, since it is prefix-matching, unless you are particular about the order of the directives, but even then it could result in a malformed redirect - probably best avoided in this situation.

Comment: mrwhite might be right in that you should lose the slash before "myfolder".. have you checked your httpd configuration file? AllowOverride All    and Options FollowSymLinks should be mentioned.. with that the Redirect example i sent you works for me. I am not using RewriteRules

Comment: "Redirect example i sent you works for me" - But be aware that the `Redirect` example above will also redirect `/folder/old_url` to `/new_path/old_url`. So you will need a more specific redirect before this (order matters).

Comment: I beg to differ @MrWhite  : Redirect 301 /oldfolder https://newsite/newpath will not redirect to  https://newsite/oldfolder , I have tested using delevoper tools and no such redirection is made, only the expected one

Comment: That's not what I said. (The example URL I used is taken from the question, to highlight the conflict with the directive you posted.) The `Redirect` directive is _prefix-matching_ and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. (It is this "feature" of the `Redirect` directive that allows you to migrate an entire site to a new domain on a different server with a simple directive, eg. `Redirect / https://newsite.com/` - this directive doesn't just redirect the document root, it redirects `/<anything>` to `https://newsite.com/<anything>`.)

Comment: To clarify, it would redirect `/folder/foo` to `/new_path/foo`, when the desired target is just `/new_path/`. The OP uses `/myfolder/old_url` to `/new_url_2` as an example in the question. (As well as `/myfolder` to `/new_url_1`.)